# Error: Access Denied when starting sharepoint 2007 workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions, access-denied

I've done my fair share of searching and still can not find a solution.  I've created a simple workflow in Sharepoint 2007 designer.  When I check the box "Start this workflow when a new item is created" I get error: access denied.  I can upload the workflow when I uncheck this box however, I can not manually start the workflow.  Same error.

I am a farm admin, site admin, collects admin.  All options are checked in User Permissions for Web Application under Central Administration.  I've tried the check in /out fix with no results.  Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to check out the workflow, and check it back in? It seems as though it might be a bug in SharePoint Designer 2007...

Link:
http://www.elorg.net/2010/04/dreaded-access-denied-on-spd-workflows/